# Free stock photos for ebook cover

Tags: self-publishing

Following my question [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8062/manipulating-standard-stock-photos-for-ebook-cover), I am wondering what are the pros and cons of using images/photos from websites that offer free stock photos. I am aware of [MorgueFiles](http://morguefile.com/).

My goal is to use the images/photos to create my ebook covers.

I want to be able to manipulate the photos (e.g. recolour or use layers). The less restriction the better.

I am aware of paid sites such as [Thinkstock](http://www.thinkstockphotos.com.au/?countrycode=AUS) but their licensing arrangements are beyond my budget. They offer 5 images for $120!

Are there other reputable sites that offer free images/photos that can meet my needs?

Comment: Wonder why the down vote

Comment: The use of stock photos for cover design, IMHO, is more on-topic at [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). While questions asking for lists of resources are generally off-topic, questions on [where to find free/low-cost stock images](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-free-stock-images) and the copyright implications of using [derivatives](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/935/can-i-use-portions-of-stock-images-for-derivative-works) (i.e. manipulations) of those images have been asked and answered there.

Comment: Basically, that's not the website to ask all questions that a writer has regarding his writing & publishing process, but only for those which are actually about writing or publishing in particular. You're asking about photo licenses, which is completely different thing. Do you really expect people at writers' website to be experts on the topic of free stock photos? OK, many of us are web developers, but it's not the place for such topics.

Comment: The system doesn't allow me to migrate this to the Graphic Design site, but there's no reason you can't just ask this there. They seem to be okay with recommendation questions like this as long as there's a specific problem to be solved. For more, here's their [meta post on recommendation questions.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/278/should-we-allow-recommendation-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.deviantart.com/ is a great site were people can post images. It works also as a social network and there you will find amazing photos: some you can use for free, some you can use if you pay a fee. Try to check there. You will find also people who have stock accounts. The trick pay attention because some pictures are free to use, by CC license, some you also can use if you pay.

And for your question, I have used free stock sites before since I am a web developer and what I could say it that I don't remember any reason why not to, as long as you pay attention if the image can be used.